# Row count to Label and adding 1 to Label Count

Tags: c#, datagridview, count

I'm trying to Create Unique ID to add to Datagridview (adding is turned off on the grid) so i Count the rows as the data is filled. I have a label that shows the count. what i am trying to do is say the count is "75" I hit New then the count becomes "76" but I know it is something stupid and simple.

This is a program for Inventory basically, running off MySQL (phpMyAdmin) server online, and talking to the Windows application.

```
// Read in the value again.
int count = ++_x;
//Get Count and Add 1 (74 to 75 to 76 etc..
lblCount.Text = dataGridView1.Rows.Count.ToString() + (_x.ToString());
//Update the ID from lblCount Text
txtID.Text = lblCount.Text;
```

Adding 1 from whatever number the Label lblCount has in it.

Comment: You're combining the count (from two sources) together into a single string. Try one or the other method, not both.

Comment: Im getting the count from the datagridview then including the count from _x to round to the next number is what i was trying to do.

Comment: lblCount.Text = "75" (Number of rows from Datagridview)
txtID.Text = lblCount.Text + _X.ToString();
Results in 751 instead of 76 is my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private int _lastCount;

public void MyProc()
{
    //Get Count and Add 1 (74 to 75 to 76 etc..
    int count = _lastCount + 1;
    lblCount.Text = count.ToString();

    //Update the ID 
    txtID.Text = count.ToString();

    _lastCount = count;
}
```

otherwise you're adding two strings together, and the add operation with strings concatenates them.

Comment: Ok that work's but what if the Label already has the number (75) in it...im getting the count from datagridview rows that are shown and and the Label holds the count already. so i just want to add to what number is in the label already